# Is there something better than a For loop in Java for iterating neatly through a collection?

Tags: java, foreach

I've been spoiled by C# with the Foreach. Is there something like this for Java?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, the [enhanced for loop](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) which was introduced in Java 1.5:

```
List<String> strings = getStringsFromSomewhere();
for (String x : strings)
{
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

It works on arrays and anything implementing `Iterable<T>` (or the raw `Iterable` type).

See [section 14.14.2 of the JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.14.2) for more details.

Comment: Is there anything you DON'T know? :P Thanks, and BTW great C# book.

Comment: @Sergio: Well I write Java during the day, so this isn't a biggie for me :) Glad you're enjoying the book.

Answer (score 5):

Java has for...each loops also - in fact, most languages do!

You can use a for...each loop with syntax like this:

> for( dataType value : collection )
>   { /*code*/ }

You can find more information, as well as code examples and demo programs, [at Java's online documentation](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html).

Comment: To be fair, Java didn't have the foreach syntax for some time (introduced Java 5, I think?)